# How can I make a dummy directory tree with dummy files that contain realistic data?

Tags: directory, directory-structure, test, data

I'm looking for preferably a one-liner that drops a directory tree a few layers deep with files that contain "realistic" data, as in, not /dev/zero nor /dev/urandom. Data that noticeably compresses when tar.gz'd.

Is this possible using existing tools or do I have to write my own?

Comment: cp -a /etc stuff

Comment: Could you give an example of what are you trying to accomplish? Not in comments, [edit] the question.

Comment: Wrt "realistic data", you may want to consider [`Beautiful Soup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser))